# Aggregate time series data, get average without NA or 0s in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate my time series data, and I want to get the average value of the aggregated value without including NAs or 0s.

Here is what my data looks like.

```
                     V1      423 470  473 626
 1: 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.00000   0  0.0   0
 2: 2018-01-01 00:01:00  8.00000   0 95.0   0
 3: 2018-01-01 00:02:00  0.00000   0  0.0   0
 4: 2018-01-01 00:03:00 31.00000   0 24.5   0
 5: 2018-01-01 00:04:00 37.00000  28 33.0  31
```

I am trying to aggregate in 5 minute interval,
and my expected output is

```
                   V1      423 470  473 626
  2018-01-01 00:05:00 34.00000  28 50.8  31
                         ~
: 2018-01-01 00:10:00        A   B    C   D
```

How do I aggregate them in 5 minute interval while getting the average value **excluding 0 s or NA s** ?

EDIT

```
structure(list(V1 = c("2018-01-01 00:00:00", "2018-01-01 00:01:00", 
"2018-01-01 00:02:00", "2018-01-01 00:03:00", "2018-01-01 00:04:00", 
"2018-01-01 00:05:00", "2018-01-01 00:06:00", "2018-01-01 00:07:00", 
"2018-01-01 00:08:00", "2018-01-01 00:09:00", "2018-01-01 00:10:00", 
"2018-01-01 00:11:00", "2018-01-01 00:12:00", "2018-01-01 00:13:00", 
"2018-01-01 00:14:00", "2018-01-01 00:15:00", "2018-01-01 00:16:00", 
"2018-01-01 00:17:00", "2018-01-01 00:18:00", "2018-01-01 00:19:00"
), `423` = c(0, 8, 0, 31, 37, 31, 26.1111111111111, 39.375, 35.5, 
19.3, 21.5454545454545, 41.2, 31, 27.375, 31, 24.3076923076923, 
26.1666666666667, 24, 26.8, 30.8181818181818), `470` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 27, 21, 0, 21.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 46, 19.5, 
0), `473` = c(0, 95, 0, 24.5, 33, 55, 50, 0, 47, 45, 0, 0, 35.4, 
0, 0, 23, 32.5, 0, 0, 55), `626` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 26, 0, 0, 
0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000029131ff1ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses `cut` to make of column `V1` a grouping variable by 5 minutes intervals and then summarizes using a custom function to compute means without `NA`'s or zero values. I have left this function in two code lines to make it more readable but it could simply be

```
f <- function(x) mean(x[x != 0], na.rm = TRUE)
```

The date time column `V1` is first coerced to class `"POSIXct"`.

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(x){
  y <- x[x != 0]
  mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)
}

df[, V1 := as.POSIXct(V1)]
df[, V1 := cut(V1, "5 mins")]
df[, lapply(.SD, f), by = V1]
#                    V1      423      470      473 626
#1: 2018-01-01 00:00:00 25.33333 28.00000 50.83333  31
#2: 2018-01-01 00:05:00 30.25722 24.00000 49.25000  21
#3: 2018-01-01 00:10:00 30.42409 21.50000 35.40000  75
#4: 2018-01-01 00:15:00 26.41851 25.16667 36.83333  48
```

A one-liner could be

```
df[, lapply(.SD, f), by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1), "5 mins")]
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error: 
: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format    error in selecting method in function 'cut'? what format should V1 be?

Comment: Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 44040 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1 : chr  "2018-01-01 00:00:00" "2018-01-01 00:01:00" "2018-01-01 00:02:00" "2018-01-01 00:03:00" ...
 $ 423: num  0 8 0 31 37 ...
 $ 470: num  0 0 0 0 28 0 0 0 27 21 ...
 $ 473: num  0 95 0 24.5 33 55 50 0 47 45 ...
 $ 626: num  0 0 0 0 31 26 0 0 0 16 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>

Comment: @YunHyunsoo `V1` sould be of class `"POSIXct"`. In the comment where you post the output of `str` it's a `chr`. That's why I first coerce to datetime with `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: @YunHyunsoo Try running `df[, V1 := as.POSIXct(V1)]` or `df$V1 <- as.POSIXct(df$V1)` and see what `str(df)` gives. If it's now a POSXct column, the rest should work as expected.

Comment: I have successfully changed the V1 class to "POSIXct" format. but I keep getting the following error 

Error in `[.data.frame`(BB, , lapply(.SD, f), by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1),  : 
  unused argument (by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1), "5 mins"))

I cannot understand my error code though..

Comment: @YunHyunsoo Have you loaded `library(data.table)`?

Comment: yes i have solved the error after library(data.table). I apologize for the bothering. Thank you so much for the explanation. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> df %>% mutate(ID = rep(letters[1:ceiling(nrow(df)/5)], each = 5)) %>% 
+               group_by(as.numeric(as.factor(ID))) %>% 
+                       select(-c(v1,ID)) %>% summarise(across(`423`:`625`,~ mean(.x[which(.x>0)]))) %>% 
+                                 select(-1) %>% mutate(v1 =  seq.POSIXt(ymd_hms('2018-01-01 00:05:00'), by = '5 mins', length.out = n()))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  `423` `470` `473` `625` v1                 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1  25.3    28  50.8    31 2018-01-01 00:05:00
2  20.7    26  49.7    32 2018-01-01 00:10:00
>
```

Data used:

```
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   v1                  `423` `470` `473` `625`
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2018-01-01 00:00:00     0     0   0       0
 2 2018-01-01 00:01:00     8     0  95       0
 3 2018-01-01 00:02:00     0     0   0       0
 4 2018-01-01 00:03:00    31     0  24.5     0
 5 2018-01-01 00:04:00    37    28  33      31
 6 2018-01-01 00:05:00     0     0   0       0
 7 2018-01-01 00:06:00     8     0  95       0
 8 2018-01-01 00:07:00     0     0   0       0
 9 2018-01-01 00:08:00    30     0  20       0
10 2018-01-01 00:09:00    24    26  34      32
>
```

Running on new Data:

```
> dput(BB)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1514764800, 1514764860, 1514764920, 
1514764980, 1514765040, 1514765100, 1514765160, 1514765220, 1514765280, 
1514765340, 1514764800, 1514764860, 1514764920, 1514764980, 1514765040, 
1514765100, 1514765160, 1514765220, 1514765280, 1514765340), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), `423` = c(0, 8, 0, 31, 37, 31, 26.1111111111111, 
39.375, 35.5, 19.3, 21.5454545454545, 41.2, 31, 27.375, 31, 24.3076923076923, 
26.1666666666667, 24, 26.8, 30.8181818181818), `470` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 27, 21, 0, 21.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 46, 19.5, 
0), `473` = c(0, 95, 0, 24.5, 33, 55, 50, 0, 47, 45, 0, 0, 35.4, 
0, 0, 23, 32.5, 0, 0, 55), `626` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 26, 0, 0, 
0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 0, 0, 48, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
> BB$V1 <- ymd_hms(BB$V1)
> BB %>% mutate(ID = rep(letters[1:ceiling(nrow(BB)/5)], each = 5)) %>% 
+   group_by(as.numeric(as.factor(ID))) %>% 
+   select(-c(V1,ID)) %>% summarise(across(`423`:`626`,~ mean(.x[which(.x>0)]))) %>% 
+   select(-1) %>% mutate(V1 =  seq.POSIXt(ymd_hms('2018-01-01 00:05:00'), by = '5 mins', length.out = n()))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  `423` `470` `473` `626` V1                 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1  25.3  28    50.8    31 2018-01-01 00:05:00
2  30.3  24    49.2    21 2018-01-01 00:10:00
3  30.4  21.5  35.4    75 2018-01-01 00:15:00
4  26.4  25.2  36.8    48 2018-01-01 00:20:00
>
```

Comment: Sorry Karthik, the error states that "ID" is not identified. could you explain what ID indicates? Thank you for the effort

Comment: So I am adding an ID column, one ID value for 5 rows i.e. for every 5 minute interval, so that I can group the values based on ID and perform aggregation. BTW, It ran for me and produced the output as shown above. On which step are you getting that error?

Comment: I am not sure.. I used BB instead of df which is the name of my data frame, and used this code BB %>% mutate(ID = rep(letters[1:ceiling(nrow(BB)/5)], each = 5)) %>% 
  +               group_by(as.numeric(as.factor(ID))) %>% 
  +                       select(-c(v1,ID)) %>% summarise(across(`423`:`625`,~ mean(.x[which(.x>0)]))) %>% 
  +                                 select(-1) %>% mutate(v1 =  seq.POSIXt(ymd_hms('2018-01-01 00:05:00'), by = '5 mins', length.out = n()))

Comment: Could you test it on the edited question. I used dput to add my data. maybe the column V1 should be numeric?

Comment: Can you please check now, I think I missed to mention  BB$V1 <- ymd_hms(df$v1)  step in my first code.

Comment: I getting an error running the code
BB$V1 <- ymd_hms(df$v1)

Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  RHS of assignment to existing column 'V1' is zero length but not NULL. If you intend to delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; e.g., NA_integer_. If you are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, as with all column type changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in the new column.

i apologize for my poor explanation.  Sorry Karthik

Comment: Can you please check now, edited my code, It is ymd_hms(BB$V1), works fine for me now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222888/discussion-between-yun-hyunsoo-and-karthik-s).